# Send File using ajax jquery and read it at back end using Flask

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to send a file using ajax jquery from the front end.

> HTML

```
<label>Upload File </label>
<form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' id='uploaded_file'>
    <button id="submit-file">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

> JavaScript

```
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submit-file").click(function(event){

            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append("uploaded_File_Name","MyFile");
            form_data.append("file",$("#uploaded_file").prop('files')[0]);
            

            $.ajax({
                url:"/read_uploaded_file",
                type:"POST",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("Successful data upload");
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("Error !!");
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the back end, I am using flask to read the file.

```
@app.route('/read_uploaded_file',method=["GET","POST"])
def read_uploaded_file():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
```

I get an error message **POST (URL) 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)**, Am i doing something wrong here? How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> POST (URL) 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) error is due to the Cross Origin
> Resource Sharing (CORS).

To solve this added CORS at the backed:

```
from flask_cors import CORS

app= Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Comment: CORS generates `Bad Request 400` error, not `Method not allowed 405`.

Comment: Strange, when i use the above line. The error is gone?

Comment: You still have `method=["GET","POST"]`? It is `methods` actually. `method` should not work.

Comment: Please answer the question thats asked, i have already fixed this issue...